# Should we upvote/accept unclear answer on meta?

Tags: discussion, meta

Currently some answers to (meta questions asking whether something is allowed) stands on both side, and some are highly voted and accepted because people standing on both side think it on his/her own side. Easily fall into, but should we? If not, what to do with such thing?

Comment: Hmm. I believe I understand what you mean, but could you link to a real-life example?

Comment: Generally, the current consensus on any policy is the most up-voted answer on a question that discusses said policy. If you find a policy that does not seem to be clearly decided on yet, you can always ask a follow-up policy question and hope for a clearer consensus.

Comment: What about unclear questions? ;)

Comment: @mbomb007 There's already "unclear" button there

Answer (score 2):

If a meta answer is unclear or ambiguous, I'd comment to say so.

If a meta answer makes the case for both sides of an argument, demonstrating that the decision is not clear cut and should be considered carefully on a case by case basis, then I'd upvote (unless I disagree in which case I'd comment/answer).